# Maven dependencies not being added to WEB-INF/lib

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, tomcat

Fairly new to Spring, Maven, Tomcat and all, I am trying to set up a Spring Web Project in Eclipse, using Maven then deploy the project to Tomcat.

I am following this tutorial, suggested by a SOF member : http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/08/spring-maven-web-application-in-eclipse.html

I am having troubles to have Maven add the dependencies specified in `pom.xml`, to Tomcat's `WEB-INF/lib`. I have scrupulously followed the steps, but in the part "Run Spring Maven project in eclipse", I do not get the same deployment assembly screenshot. This is what I get :

[image: Web deployment assembly in Eclipse, after running <code>mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0</code>]

I checked in Eclipse that WTP is here, and it is (Help -> Install new Software -> Link "what is installed?") However the version I see for m2e-wtp is 1.0.**. SO I tried to run the `mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=1.0` command (using version 1.0 instead of 2.0) but still the same problem...

Anybody has had the same problem ? I have seen similar questions, tried what was suggested but nothing worked for me unfortunately. For example I went in Web Deployment Assembly and clicked `Add` -> `Java Build Path Entries` but I don't see a `Maven Dependencies` checkbox : what I see is a list of entries of the form `M2_REPO/.../...`

Happy Holidays everyone, and thanks in advance for any help on this
Myna

Comment: upload your pom.xml file

Comment: I did the update as the tutorial suggested. Is that what you were reffering to @KamleshArya ?

Comment: What exactly is incorrect about your deployment assembly?  It's not identical but the gist seems to be the same.  The differences could simply be discrepancies in plugin versions.  Yours appears newer.

Comment: Never ever mix m2e and the maven-eclipse plugin, they have different strategies and are not compatible with each other. The maven-eclipse plugin will generate eclipse files based on the pom. Any modification in the `pom.xml` requires you to close eclipse, run `eclipse:eclipse` and restart eclipse. m2e is the preferred way: it will dynamically update the eclipse project if you make changes.

Answer (score 15):

Looks like your "Deployment Assembly" is missing the *Maven Dependencies* being added to the packaging structure of your project. 
The way this should look is:

[image]

The way to add that in is: 
- click on `Add` 
- select `Java Build Path Entries` 
- select `Maven Dependencies` 
- `Finish`

That should add your Maven Dependencies into `WEB-INF/lib`. 
In case your project structure is not standard, you can also edit that path by double-clicking inside your `Deploy Path` column - in this case, on `WEB-INF/lib`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @Eugen the only thing is that I don't have the option to select `Maven Dependencies` after I do `Add` -> `Java Build Path Entries`...

Comment: Is your project a Maven project? You can check by looking in your `.project` file - does it have `<nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>`. If not - Right Click - Configure - Convert to Maven project.

Answer (score 4):

Open your project folder and find the .classpath file,edit it and add follow code

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

Comment: while using m2e you should not modify any eclipse project file. they are managed by m2e.. use ALT-F5 to update these files with m2e...

Answer (score 1):

I have just had the same problem after improting a new maven web project in my newly created workspace.
I checked everything mentioned above: by @Eugen, @lucky, @Cary - all of this was already presented in my project.

I solved my problem by right-clikcing on my it and selecting Maven-->Update Project

Comment: This should be  a comment

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have the reputation to comment yet. But you could delte this post and add it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have Maven installed in your eclipse version you use. However you can  install `Maven Integration for Eclipse` from the Eclipse Market place. Just Go to Help => Eclipse MarketPlace and Type Maven Integration and install the Maven Integration for eclipse.

Once you are done eclipse will restart and you will be able to see your jars in the Dependency management as Maven Dependencies.

Visit this url for more info Hope this helps.
[m2eclipse](http://maven.apache.org/eclipse-plugin.html)

Comment: Hello @Lucky thanks for replying. I have tried, but I get a "Problem occured, there is nothing to update".

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/SN4Rv.png    Install the plugin Maven Integration for Eclipse (third one in the image)..