# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoadListener

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat7, classnotfoundexception

I have been struggling with this problem for a few days now (That is why I am providing GitHub link). 
Here is the stack trace:

```
    SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoadListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoadListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4854)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I will point only, that I use Tomcat 7 and I run the server from Servers tab in Eclipse.

I have read everything in the Internet about it. The most common solution provided was:

> "Go to project properties -> Deployment Assembley, click Add... ,
>   select Java Build Path Entries and add the Maven Dependencies to the
>   Web Deployment Assembly."

And it does not work for me, same as other solutions in the Internet I have seen so far. I am hopeless.

I am providing GitHub link to my project: https://github.com/wiewioraseb/beer-blog-hiccup.git
I already tried to export it to another computer, I still get the same error while running it on the other machine.

Comment: Sometimes cleaning tomcat resolves the Issue. And Do you see "Maven Dependencies" folder in your project libraries?

Comment: @SRy I have done that already unfortunately. I see Maven Dependencies in my project library.

Comment: can you post your project structure here?

Comment: @SRy Here you go http://s10.postimg.org/ckjrs4ogp/project.jpg

Comment: For me your deployment assembly looks wrong. Maven project structure should be `src/main/java`. Check your deployment assembly looking like this http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://i.stack.imgur.com/Q19bw.png&imgrefurl=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718566/maven-dependencies-not-being-added-to-web-inf-lib&h=625&w=971&tbnid=xT2p-Ax3R_smSM:&zoom=1&docid=z4dJgzMkzaB5gM&ei=rOf1VM7mAszFggSdzoIY&tbm=isch&ved=0CB4QMygBMAE. And remove  tomcat 7 library from classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct listener class to bootstrap Spring root context is ContextLoaderListener, not ContextLoadListener! So in web.xml should be:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: I`m embarrassed now, Sorry for inconvenience! And thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-error-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-context-contextloaderlistener/) says:
In deployment environment, just make sure your server classpath has included the Spring jar library (e.g spring-2.5.6.jar).

For Spring3, ContextLoaderListener is moved to spring-web.jar, you can get the library from Maven central repository.

```html
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Do you mean to copy spring-2.5.6.jar (or spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar)  to C:\something\Tomcat7\lib directory? If not, where can I find server classpath?

Comment: But If OP exactly used the POM.xml whatever he copied from `github` link, he doesn't need to do anything. I suspect OP is missing some configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your build path (within eclipse) actually includes all the dependencies (in this case specifically spring-web und spring-webmvc)?
If you build a *.war file, using `mvn clean install`, the libraries will probably be included in it, if you unpack it.

However, this is not the same as Eclipse. Therefore I suggest running `mvn clean install eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse` within your directory. Then refresh the project in Eclipse and clean it as well (Project -> Clean).

To see if libraries are deployed properly, double click on your server and go to this location (in your workspace folder):

[image: tomcat eclipse directory]

and check for the dependencies (*.jar files) inside your `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

Generally this fixes the problem for me. You should:

- close the server in Eclipse
- rightclick -> clean -> clean Tomcat Work Directory
- run the commands above
- start the server

Comment: I made a .war file and unpacked it to check if the libraries are there. Everything is fine with it. 
I have already cleaned the directory, didn`t help ;(

Comment: I checked if the libraries are there: C:\something\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\beer-blog-hiccup\WEB-INF\lib
and they are all in place. @Schaka